# How to link fixed images on Tumblr CSS?

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, linker, tumblr

For my Tumblr theme, I want to have these 4 fixed images on the right side of the screen to be linked to another page.

[My Tumblr's link](http://rebekahkroeplin.tumblr.com/).

Here's the HTML for 1 of the images:

```
<img src="http://i851.photobucket.com/albums/ab71/rachelala101/fandomsbuttons1-1_zps43ab3b55.png" id="icon1" width="90px">
```

Here's the CSS for it:

```
#icon1 {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    right:20px;
    top:60px;
    z-index:130
}
```

I tried using the  tag to link it, but then the images disappear completely.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow,

You should use the tag anchor `a` as you mentioned. Here is a working sample, replace `#` with your link.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i851.photobucket.com/albums/ab71/rachelala101/fandomsbuttons1-1_zps43ab3b55.png" id="icon1" width="90px" class="icon1_rollover"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i851.photobucket.com/albums/ab71/rachelala101/fandoms%20buttons%201-1-2_zpsynh4farl.png" id="icon2" width="90px" class="icon2_rollover"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i851.photobucket.com/albums/ab71/rachelala101/fandomsbuttons1-3_zps10c8734d.png" id="icon3" width="90px" class="icon2_rollover"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    position:fixed;
    right:20px;
    top:60px;
    z-index:130;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

you may want to read this [tutorial](http://studentwebhosting.com/tutorials/css-based-menu-with-images/).

Nice blog by the way.